# WPF Extended Textbox Override not working correctly

Tags: wpf, textbox, overriding, metadata, custom-controls

I have created a CustomTextBox which extends TextBox.

I have overridden the Metadata for TextProperty because I want to trigger a method when the text changes, but when I run my code and edit the textbox, I am only seeing the OnTextPropertyChanged event fired twice. First time when I initialise the textbox, and the second when I close the window.

How can I have this fired for each keystroke in the Textbox?

AppTextBox.cs:

```
public class AppTextBox : TextBox
{
    static AppTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AppTextBox),
                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                          string.Empty,
                                          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                                          OnTextPropertyChanged,
                                          null,
                                          true,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged)
                                      );

        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AppTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AppTextBox)));
    }

    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // TODO: Check if Text is null or empty...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ctrl:AppTextBox Text="{Binding NewWord.WrittenForm}" />
```

So when I first load the textbox, the content is "Foo".

When I add or delete a letter, I would expect the OnTextPropertyChanged to be fired, but it is not. Should I be doing something different to achieve my goal?

Comment: That property changed event made no difference at all.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that is what I tried and it made no difference

Comment: Why don't you just override [OnTextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.ontextchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-primitives-textboxbase-ontextchanged(system-windows-controls-textchangedeventargs))?

Comment: It's a small piece of code that is absolutely correct. Still, I have tested your code and as expected it behaves the way you expect it to behave. It must be related to the binding source. Check that NewWord.WrittenForm property is not rejecting the value that is send from the AppTextBox. The WrittenForm property must also raise the PropertyChanged event.  The AppTextBox itself is correctly implemented and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `propdp` can be simplified.

```
public partial class AppTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static new readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AppTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged)));
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnTextPropertyChanged");
    }

    public AppTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The trick is to provide binding on the derived control

```
x:Name="self"
Text="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

and here's the full control

```
<TextBox x:Class="WpfApp10.AppTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
         x:Name="self"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignWidth="800"
         d:DesignHeight="450"/>
```

Comment: This binds the Text property to the same Text property. Declaring a new dependency property like this is complete nonsense.

Comment: Also `ElementName=self` with `x:Name="self"` is pointless. Use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` in such a scenario.

Comment: There is `class AppTextBox : TextBox`. You should try out what you are posting here. There is no UserControl in the question, and none to be invented for a useless problem solution.

Comment: Even if there would be a UserControl with a TextBox child, `x:Name` should *of course* not be on the TextBox, but on the UserControl. You did never test this.

Comment: There you have it.
https://github.com/JazwinskiMichal/AppTextBox

Comment: If it's new or not familiar to you, it does not mean that it's wrong answer and *nobody* will understand it. Mine example does exactly what OP wanted. I suggest more kind approach next time.

Comment: It does perhaps with additional explanation. How should anybody understand the strange idea of first creating a UserControl and then changing its base class without explaining that?  It is the most complicated way to solve the problem described in the question. In general, when you see `new` on a member declaration, you are already on the wrong track. It is more than wrong, even if it somehow works.

Comment: As you may conclude from comments on the question, the original approach of the question asker is actually working. It is way simpler than what you are showing here, and still too complicated.